# Proof that the change of basis matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

I'm going to briefly describe my idea and solution, which I don't know if it's correct, but I think it should be.

> Suppose we have two basis $f$ and $e$ for a vector space $V$. We know
>   that the vectors of $e$ can be represented as a linear combination of
>   the vectors in $f$, since, by definition, $f$ spans $V$.
>
> The change of basis matrix from $F = \begin{pmatrix} f_1 & \cdots &
>  f_n \end{pmatrix}$ to $E = \begin{pmatrix} e_1 & \cdots & e_n
>  \end{pmatrix}$ is $C$ in the following formula (see [here](http://www.math.ku.edu/~lerner/LAnotes/Chapter14.pdf) for more details)
>
> $$E = F \cdot C$$
>
> Since the vectors of $F$ are linearly independent, then $F$ is
>   invertible, therefore we have
>
> $$F^{-1}E = C$$
>
> $E$ is also invertible for the same reason.
>
> We know that a matrix $X$ is invertible **if and only if** $\det(X)
>  \neq 0$.
>
> Thus we have
>
> $$det(C) = det(F^{-1} \cdot E) = det(F^{-1}) \cdot det(E) \neq 0$$
>
> Since $det(C) \neq 0$, then $C$ is invertible.

Answer (score 3):

If I have understood your question properly, the argument should be the following. First of all
$$
E = F \cdot C,
$$
as you said. But then since $E$ is also a basis, there is a matrix $D$ such that
$$
F = E \cdot D.
$$ 
Therefore
$$
E = F \cdot C = (E \cdot D) \cdot C = E \cdot (D \cdot C).
$$
Since $E$ is a linearly independent, this yields that $D \cdot C$ is the identity matrix. You have proved that $C$ is invertible.

---

Clearly you can do the same starting with $F = E \cdot D = \dots = F \cdot (C \cdot D)$ to see that also $C \cdot D$ is the identity, but the above suffices anyway.

Comment: My point is, what is the inverse of a row of vectors? Say you have a vector space with basis $F = (u, v)$. What is $F^{-1}$?

Comment: This is the important point: what do the columns of $F$ represent? You said $V$ is just a vector space. So given a basis $F$, how would you write it as a matrix?

Comment: Column vectors with respect to what? You said that $V$ is just a vector space, not the space of column vectors of length $n$.

Comment: And then, if the $f_{i}$ are column vectors, then $F$ is the matrix of the change of basis between the standard basis and the basis $f$. So in saying that $F$ is invertible, you are using the result you want to prove.

Comment: Yes, but it seems that you were given an abstract vector space $V$. By regarding it as a space of column vectors, you are already choosing, albeit implicitly, a basis. And then your argument becomes circular, because your $F$ becomes the matrix of a change of basis, and your problem is exactly to prove that such a matrix is invertible. Believe me, you should go along with my proof. But then my responsibility is limited to my students - you should check with your instructors whether they are happy with your argument. That's all for today.